# PHP profile update error with mysql_num_rows

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, input

I have a simple PHP page, where you can update your website profile. There are several updateable inputs like telephone number, MSN access, etc. There's one specific, the e-mail address field. Since it's not a register but an update page, the user's current email add. should appear there as the field's value. But I have a problem when the user changes the email to another one, it works fine as long as it is not in use, but when he doesn't change his email, and updates something else, it won't work.

```
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
if(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email'")) > 0)
{
    echo "The e-mail is already in use.";
}
```

How should I fix these lines, because whenever the user changes something else than the e-email, the very same form action executes and of course, the user gets the error since he changed his e-mail to his own e-mail again practically, which gives to mysql_num_rows() an 1 value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with something like that :

```
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$username =  mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']); // You can also get it from the session or wherever you want
$row = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email'");
if(mysql_num_rows($row) > 0)
{
    if ($username != $row["username"]) {
        echo "The e-mail is already in use.";
    }

}
```

It can be the username or any other information that identified the current user.

Comment: SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email'" and username !=$_postusername

Comment: Yeah it's even better to put it in the query ;o

Answer (score 0):

i suggest to take email adress of current user in the session , then you can add a condition that verify that emails selected is different than the current user email

```
"SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email' AND email !=" . $_SESSION['user_email']
```

you can also use sub-request like this

```
"SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email' AND email != (select email FROM users WHERE id= $id_of_current_user)"
```

Comment: I actually have the user's username in a session so... This one will work too!!